# Are there any tools or techniques to help determine the exact cause of a nonsecure page element error?

Tags: html, https

I run into this quite often where a new page is supposedly "tested" and ready to go. But as soon as I change the page from http to https (secure) mode I get the "This page contains both secure and nonsecure items." error.

Usually I can find the problem and fix it pretty quick. Today is different. I've checked every image reference and every javascript reference and their source and haven't found anything that should be causing this error.

Are there any developer tools or techniques that can point out specifically what is causing this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Firebug's](http://getfirebug.com/) [Net panel](http://getfirebug.com/net.html). Again, only in Firefox, although Firebug Lite might include this, I'm not sure. If it does, that'd cover this too.

Comment: that looks like a great plugin. Thanks for the link.

Comment: It really is. Editing visually in the page is a HUGE help for working out CSS issues. It's one of my personal must have plugins for web development.

Answer (score 1):

If you're in Firefox you can use Tools -> Page Info -> Media, then just scan down the list to find the non-https link. There might also be JavaScript building dynamic `<script>` tags, or CSS including non-secure elements.

Comment: Thanks! It was in the css, must be an editor the designer used. I didn't even notice it was linked because the css was referenced in the .master page not the .aspx content.

Comment: This doesn't show Javascript as far as I can tell. Still useful though.

Comment: there should be something all inclusive that can help resolve these types of "errors" quickly.

Comment: Firebug will show anything loaded in your page. There's no Secure column for determining this easily, but scrolling down and mouseing over everything will fairly quickly tell you which elements are secure and which aren't.

Comment: that is exactly what I did and found it pretty fast. it would have been nice to know that the actual source of the link was from x.css though.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add a couple of other tools should someone have this problem in the future:

- If you're using IE, there is [Fiddler.](http://www.fiddlertool.com/fiddler/)
- [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/download.html) is another tool that may be useful.